# Spring cache fails to deserialise empty array

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jackson, spring-cache

I have following Redis cache setup

```
private RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration() {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
        .disableCachingNullValues()
        .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(cacheObjectMapper())));
}

private ObjectMapper cacheObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL,
        JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

This is the cached method

```
@Cacheable("notes")
List<Note> findNotes(Long postId) {
    ...
}
```

When the method returns an empty list it's serialised as the following `[]` and on deserialisation I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught exception org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected token (END_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
 at [Source: (byte[])"[]"; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (END_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
 at [Source: (byte[])"[]"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

What am I missing here?

**# Update**

I changed the default typing to `ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING` like this:

```
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance,
    ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);
```

It got rid of the error but still, maybe someone has other ideas on how to get rid of the error.

Comment: Had the same problem. Solved. Thank's!